# PDO use in multiple functions - reuse of prepared statement

Tags: php, pdo

I have a class "test" with 2 functions, one to create the prepared statement and one to execute one or more times. The problem is how do i set the binding in the first one and fill in the vars on the other function.

```
class test {

    private static $moduleSql = "SELECT 
                                            id,
                                            module
                                        FROM 
                                            phs_pages
                                        WHERE 
                                            prettyurl = :prettyUrl AND
                                            mainId = :mainId
                                            ";

    private static function pre() {
        $db = Db_Db::getInstance();
        self::$preModuleSql = $db->prepare(self::$moduleSql);
        self::$preModuleSql->bindParam(':prettyUrl', $prettyUrl);
        self::$preModuleSql->bindParam(':mainId', $mainId);
    }

    private static function getClassByDb($mainId = 0, $id = 0) {
        $prettyUrl = self::$parts[$id];
        self::$preModuleSql->execute();
        self::$preModuleSql->debugDumpParams();
        $result = self::$preModuleSql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // get lower level classes

        if (isset(self::$parts[$id + 1])) {
            self::getClassByDb($result['id'], $id + 1);
        } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don´t need to bind any parameters in your first function, you need to do that in your second function, right before you execute the prepared statement.

**Edit:** By the way, you can also call [execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) with an array that contains your parameters as keys and the values you want to send.

Comment: This is what I do. It works remarkably well. If there's a desire for it, I'll post my code in an answer, but it's pretty bog-standard PHP.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many things wrong with this class definition .. ehh.

It should look like this :

```
class RepositoryException extends Exception{}

interface iRepository
{
    public function store( $key , PDOStatement  $statement );
    public function fetch( $key );
}

class StatementRepository implements iRepository{

    protected $_pool = array();

    public function store( $key , PDOStatement  $statement )
    {
        $this->_pool[ $key ] = $statement;
    }
    public function fetch( $key )
    {
        if ( !array_key_exists( $key , $this->_pool ) ){
            throw new RepositoryException( 
                "Statement with name '$key' does not exist" );
        }

        return $this->_pool[ $key ];
    }
}

$repo = new StatementRepository;

$foo = new Foo( $repo );
$bar = new Bar( $repo );

$db = new PDO('sqlite::memory:');
$statement = $db->prepare( 'SELECT .... ');

$repo->store( 'bljum' , $statement );
```

This way all the object which have accepted in the constructor an object which implements `iRepository` can `fetch` statements by name.

You class should not have more responsibilities then it needs. If it is for storing prepared statements , then it should have nothing to do with binding parameters to them and executing something.

Here is what Foo class would do :

```
class Foo
{
    protected $_repo = null;

    public function __construct( iRepository $repo )
    {
        $this->_repo = $repo;
    }

    public function ergo( $x , $y )
    {
        $statement = $this->_repo->fetch('bljum');
        //bind values
        $statement->execute();
    }

}
```